# NullPointerException using PriorityQueue

Tags: java, collections, graph

I make a simple adjacent List where each node is String type
The implementation of graph is:

```
HashMap<String,HashSet<String>> //From every node to a Set of nodes...
```

But in the BFS realization i get NullPointerException 
I was playing around with it, but i don`t understand the real problem

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String,HashSet<String>> m=new HashMap();
        HashSet<String> h_s = new HashSet();
        //Now fill in the h_s
        h_s.add("B");
        h_s.add("C");
        h_s.add("D");
        //Path from A --- to --> B,C,D
        m.put("A",h_s);
        // Now let`s make a BFS
        Queue<String> q=new PriorityQueue();
        //starting from A
        q.add("A");
        String current_vertex;
        while (!q.isEmpty()) {
            current_vertex = q.remove();
            //For every vertex adjacent with current_vertex
            for (String vertex_to:m.get(current_vertex)) {
                System.out.println("BFS is checking "+vertex_to);
                q.add(vertex_to);//This line causing NullPointerException
            }
        }
    }
```

However, if we delete line

```
q.add(vertex_to)
```

everything work pretty fine
Which confuse me even more.
Explain please in detail, cause i think i`m missing smt important
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your map only has the "A" key, so when you add "B", "C" and "D" to the queue, and later remove them from the queue, `m.get(current_vertex)` returns null.

You have to check if the key is in the map:

```
    while (!q.isEmpty()) {
        current_vertex = q.remove();
        //For every vertex adjacent with current_vertex
        if (m.containsKey(current_vertex) {
            for (String vertex_to:m.get(current_vertex)) {
                System.out.println("BFS is checking "+vertex_to);
                q.add(vertex_to);//This line causing NullPointerException
            }
        }
    }
```